# Link_to "Read Me" won't show when following the tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby-on-Rails via tutorial that is on Youtube. !! apologize if my terminology is not correct, I know coding has its own language and I am learning.

In Post index html.erb I want a link_to button to show next to my text. I have followed every step of the tutorial and I double check for any error, typo, missing a comma, symbol.

I looked online for RubyonRail explanation to Link_to and It shows the code below "correctly". Still, I did not make it to work

```
<p><%= truncate(post.content, length: 100, separator: '') { link_to "Read More", post_path(post) } %></p>
```

This morning I got frustrated and ended up making a new paragraph with Link_to on its own. IT WORKED!

```
<p><%= truncate(post.content, length: 100, separator: '') %><%= link_to "Read More", post_path(post) %></p>
```

I would appreciate an explanation of why the first syntax doesn't work. and is the way I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the First syntax, you are getting this error because you are using `html.erb` file

`erb` stands for "Embedded Ruby". A .html.erb or .erb.html file is HTML with Ruby code embedded in; Rails will evaluate the Ruby to add content to the file dynamically.

`<%=` **Expression-printing tags** inserts values into the output. It starts with an opening tag delimiter and equals sign `(<%=)` and ends with a closing tag delimiter `(%>)`. It must contain a snippet of Ruby code that resolves to value;

for more details, you can have a look [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_template_erb.html#expression-printing-tags)